# Run a single typescript file using ts-node inside an NX monorepo

Tags: typescript, monorepo, ts-node, nomachine-nx

I am trying to run a single TypeScript file inside an `NX` monorepo using `ts-node` but I keep getting errors when importing local modules.

```
npx ts-node  apps/sanity/src/sanity.ts 
(node:22816) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Setting `"type": "module"` in the `package.json` in the workspace root, and then running the command again results in this error:

```
npx ts-node  apps/sanity/src/sanity.ts 
Unknown file extension ".ts" for /Users/maverik/Projects/project-zed/apps/sanity/src/sanity.ts
    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
    at Loader.defaultGetFormat [as _getFormat] (internal/modules/esm/get_format.js:71:15)
    at Loader.getFormat (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:105:42)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:243:31)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:177:17)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (internal/modules/run_main.js:59:12) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
```

How can I run a single typescript file using `ts-node` inside an NX monorepo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a new `tsconfig.demo.json` file to the project with the following options:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "types": ["node"],
    "module": "ESNext",            // this option
    "moduleResolution": "Node",    // this option
    "esModuleInterop": true        // this option 

  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,                   // this option
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node". // this option
  },
  "exclude": ["jest.config.ts", "src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.test.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

And then ran this command:

```
npx ts-node --project apps/sanity/tsconfig.demo.json  apps/sanity/src/main.ts
```

Comment: This worked, but I then ran into issues with `ts-node` not handling the `paths` from the tsconfig file. So if you are using shared libraries inside the standalone file you want to run, you may need additional configuration. I ended up adding another entry to the `project.json` file, copying the `build` and `serve` sections and renaming them and updating the main file. This works for the problem I was solving.